# R Error in if (nrow(emobj$Mu) != nclass || ncol(emobj$Mu) != p || nrow(emobj$LTSigma) != : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, expectation-maximization

I am getting the following error while using the EMCluster library in R:

```
Error in if (nrow(emobj$Mu) != nclass || ncol(emobj$Mu) != p || nrow(emobj$LTSigma) !=  : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

This is the code I wrote:

```
emcluster(iris[,-5], pi = NULL, Mu = NULL, LTSigma = NULL,
      lab = NULL, EMC = .EMC, assign.class = FALSE)
```

I am using the Iris dataset.

My goal is to run an EM clustering algorithm and describe my observations through plots, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the parameters, or you can initialize the EM and provide that:

```
library(EMCluster)

emobj <- simple.init(iris[,-5], nclass = 3)
mdl <- emcluster(iris[,-5], emobj = emobj, assign.class = TRUE)

table(mdl$class,iris$Species)
   
    setosa versicolor virginica
  1      0          0        15
  2      0         50        35
  3     50          0         0
```